# JCodec simple H264 encode/decode

Tags: java, video, h.264, video-encoding, jcodec

Ok, so trying to get my head around jcodec. Basically, I want to record what's on the screen as BufferedImages, encode the buffered images as H264 frames and then decode them and convert them back to buffered image.

This is the code I have, the ScreenRecorder class extends thread and basically captures the screen in a while true loop. That part works. Then, it seems that encoding the BufferedImage from ScreenRecorder as a H264 frame works too but then when i try to decode it I get an AIOBE

```
ScreenRecorder sc = new ScreenRecorder();
sc.start();

    H264Encoder enc = H264Encoder.createH264Encoder();
    ColorSpace cs = enc.getSupportedColorSpaces()[0];
    System.out.println("cs= " + cs);
    H264Decoder dec = new H264Decoder();
    byte[][] buff = new byte[4096][4096];
    while (true) {
        BufferedImage bi = sc.getSnapshot();
        System.out.println("Got bi " + bi);
        if (bi != null) {
            Picture pi = AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi, cs);
            int bufSize = enc.estimateBufferSize(pi);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufSize);
            VideoEncoder.EncodedFrame ef = enc.encodeFrame(pi, bb);
            System.out.println("Data = " + Arrays.toString(ef.getData().array()));
            Frame f = dec.decodeFrame(ef.getData(), buff);
            System.out.println("Decoded frame = " + f);
        }
    }
```

Produces:

```
Got bi BufferedImage@506e1b77: type = 1 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 1920 height = 1080 #Bands = 3 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0
org.jcodec.common.VideoEncoder$EncodedFrame@1a93a7ca
Data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 66, 0, 40, -83, 0, -16, 4, 75, -54, -128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -50, 56, -128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 101, -72, 32, 13, 12, 98, -128, 0, -111, 127, -1, -3, 127, -61, 24, 0, 36, 9, 112, -96, 28, 13, -108, -43, 45, -92, -57, 7, 101, 39, 31, -4, 0, 121, -104, 17, -86, 9, 84, -111, -94, 39, 125, 94, -57, 64, 2, 67, 56, 28, 0, 4, 0, 118, -97, -128, 40, 124, 20, 39, 122, 111, -117, -124, 25, 72, -76, -107, 90, -1, -122, 48, 0, 67, 41, 10, -64, 0, 32, 106, 0, 5, -128, -108, -13, 80, 51, 112, 113, 112, 107, -1, -17, -32, 32, 85, -60, -76, 52, 70, -67, 124, 3, 113, 111, 51, 0, 1, 0, -64, 0, 16, 15, -5, -48, 3, -80, -21, -2, 24, -64, 25, -48, 0, 16, 39, 0, 1, 0, 105, -112, 13, 9, 11, -35, -16, 56, 0, 8, 6, -128, 0, -128, 80, 0, -69, -112, -32, 0, 32, 26, 0, 2, 1, 64, 2, -18, 124, 56, 0, 8, 6, -128, 0, -128, 80, 0, -69, -112, -32, 0, 32, 26, 0, 2, 1, 64, 2, -18, 47, -8, 98, 56, 0, -112, 15, 21, 96, 3, 102, 59, -124, 48, 83, 96, 55, -10, 1, 55, -6, 27, 0, 67, 19, 47, -12, 90, 112, -125, -108, 64, 38, 9, 83, 29, 101, -56, 75, -126, -85, -96, 113, 17, -105, 2, 57, 98, 56, -66, 28, 88, -105, ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.SliceDecoder.putMacroblock(SliceDecoder.java:198)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.SliceDecoder.decodeMacroblocks(SliceDecoder.java:104)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.SliceDecoder.decodeFromReader(SliceDecoder.java:73)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder$FrameDecoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:152)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrameFromNals(H264Decoder.java:103)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:99)
    at uno.anahata.satgyara.screen.ScreenRecorder.main(ScreenRecorder.java:148)
```

Just trying to figure out how jcodec works. Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems like you are feeding encoder's output ByteBuffer to decoder without calling `flip` on it first. ByteBuffers don't work that way — a buffer returned by encoder is marked as "full" with it's position set close to the end. Decoder expects the buffer to "have some space" (position set at the beginning, limit to the amount of available data).

Comment: maybe get inspired here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165593/how-to-decode-h-264-video-frame-in-java-environment

Answer (score 0):

```
Picture buf = Picture.create(pixelWidth + (pixelWidth % 16), pixelHeight + (pixelHeight % 16), ColorSpace.YUV420);
...
Frame f = dec.decodeFrame(ef.getData(), buf.getData();
```

A bit late, but maybe someone else will find my answer useful